# ng-pattern regex to find only single occurrence of a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I need to match the pattern as string `'abcd'` followed by a colon(:) and any number of integers. This pattern can not repeat.

For example,
valid pattern->

```
- abcd:23415 
- abcd:23
```

invalid pattern->

```
- asda:4535 
- abcd 
- abcdabcd:324 
- abcd:234abcd234 
- abcd:234:abcd:234
```

I tried the following:

```
((((abcd){0,1}):([0-9].+)){0,1})[^:]
```

It did not work. I need to pass this on in ng-pattern. Considering that ng-pattern by default appends ^ and adds $ at the end, please suggest the correct pattern.

Comment: Is the beginning of the string just `abcd`, a known letter sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex contains `.+` subpattern that allows any 1 or more symbols other than a newline inbetween `:` and non-`:`. Looks like it is not what you need.

Note that you can actually pass a regex, not only a string, to the `ng-pattern`.

So, if you have `abcd` in the beginning, then `:` followed by 1 or more digits, use

```
ng-pattern="/^abcd:\d+$/"
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pY3sP6/1)

See a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40ty6z5e/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try `/^abcd:\d*$/`  as pattern if number(s) at the end are optional.

Try `/^abcd:\d+$/` if number at the end are mandatory.

**Some Basic Details:**

`^` start of the test string

`abcd:` exact match for static string fragment

`\d` match for a digit

`*` occurrence zero or more times

`+` occurrence one or more times

`$` end of the test string